# Auto select the top autocomplete result into hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to do a search by id, but the autocomplete by name.
So I put an hidden input, that is updated on select.
The problem is that if the user presses `Esc` or some how initiates a search without selecting, the search fails (doesn't return the desired value), because the hidden value isn't updated. I'm trying to force the autocomplete to choose the top result as long as no other result is selected.

My code is:

```
$('#search_box').focus(function () {
            $(hidden).val("");
        });
$('#search_box').autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete_empl.asp",
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#hidden').val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0));
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

P.S

The returned list comes in json form.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if autocomplete val() is empty.
If it is empty do nothing( or you need to select the first value?)

```
$('#search_box').focus(function () {
            $(hidden).val("");
        });
$('#search_box').autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete_empl.asp",
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if($('#search_box').val() !== ""){
                   $('#hidden').val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0));
                }
            }
        });
```

If you need to select the first option just trigger the search event with the data you need

```
select: function (event, ui) {
                if($('#search_box').val() !== ""){
                   $('#hidden').val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0));
                }
                else{
                  $('#search_box').autocomplete('search', 'DataYouNeed');
                }
            }
```

Here is the link on the API page, which explains it a bit 
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

Comment: This is no good... i need the first value to be selected if no other value was selected...